# TabLayout change of tabText color

Tags: java, android, tabs, styles, android-tablayout

I am trying to get the selected tab ONLY to be in different color, please see the following code,

viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

```
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Chats "));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Services"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Favourite"));
    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(-1,-256);
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));


    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

my xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
    />
```

and my style:

```
 <style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabText</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/theme_blue</item>
</style>
```

Please help me out, to see what needs editing so that only one tab at a time gets a different colour!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using app:tabTextColor and app:tabSelectedTextColor

Like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
  app:tabTextColor="@color/theme_blue"
  app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
  style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"/>
```